# The pullback of a volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

I'm a beginner in differential geometry. I got stuck with this exercise:

Let $V$ be real $n$-dimensional vector space. Let $S(V)$ denotes the unit sphere in $V$.
Consider the map $ f: \mathbb {R}^+ \times S(V) \longrightarrow V$, $(z,v)\longmapsto \sqrt{z} v$.

If $d \rho$ and  $d \sigma$ denote the volume forms in $V$ and $S(V)$ respectively, show that $f^* (d \rho )= \frac{1}{2} z^{\frac{n-2}{2}}dz \wedge d \sigma$.

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted.

Comment: Thank you md2perpe! Well, I tried to understand it in the simpler case where V = R but i failed! I tried to  apply  the definition  of the pullback to the volume form  $dρ$:  $f^*(d\rho)(x,y)=d\rho(f_∗(x,y))=d\rho(Df(x,y))=d\rho(\frac{1}{2}x^{−\frac{1}{2}}ydx +\sqrt{x}dy$).

Comment: Is really $f^* (d \rho )= \frac{1}{2} z^{n-1}d \sigma$ correct?

Comment: Not $\frac12 z^{\frac{n-2}{2}} \, dz \wedge d\sigma$?

Comment: You're absolutely right! since in the statement of the exercise,   the dimension of V is  2n , and if it is n we'll get your formula . Sorry for these mistakes , I'll  edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $d\rho(zv) = z^{n-1} \, dz \wedge d\sigma(v)$ where $zv \in V$ with $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $v \in S(V).$ This gives the pullback
$$
f^*(d\rho)(z,v)
= (d\rho\circ f)(z,v)
= d\rho(f(z,v))
= d\rho(\sqrt{z}v) \\
= (\sqrt{z})^{n-1} d(\sqrt{z}) \wedge d\sigma(v)
= (\sqrt{z})^{n-1} \frac{dz}{2\sqrt{z}} \wedge d\sigma(v) \\
= \frac{1}{2} z^{\frac{n-2}{2}} dz \wedge d\sigma(v)
.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! but I don't understand the step where you wrote :$d\rho(\sqrt{z}v)={(\sqrt{z})}^{n-1}d(\sqrt{z}) \wedge d\sigma(v)$. Could you say more details about it please ?

Comment: @Maria. Since for $r>0$ and $v\in S(V)$ you have $d\rho(ru) = r^{n-1} du \wedge d\sigma(v)$, replacing $r$ with $\sqrt{z}$ you get $d\rho(\sqrt{z}v) = (\sqrt{z})^{n-1} d(\sqrt{z}) \wedge d\sigma(v)$.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and your help !